# Why won't Eye of Cthulhu spawn?

Tags: terraria-mobile

When I used the suspicious eye to summon Eye of Cthulhu at night, he wouldn't spawn. Is it a bug or do I need to do anything else? I have full health in red hearts, 13 defense, and I'm using a tungsten broadsword.

Answer (score 2):

You can spawn **Eye of Cthulhu** with a **Suspicious Looking Eye** only if all of the following conditions are met:

- It's nighttime *(you should summon it at nightfall anyway since it will disappear at dawn)*
- It's not raining
- You are not fighting a summoned Eye

Your item won't be consumed otherwise and nothing in particular will happen.

Answer (score -2):

Have you defeated the Cthulhu before?

When I try to spawn bosses, I always make sure that I have defeated them before first.